# How to use Temporary List with Dart?

Tags: dart

How i can get this result using Dart ?

> [Expected Result]
>   [["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"]]

```
void main() {
  var list = new List<List<String>>();
  var tempList = new List<String>();

  tempList.add("A");
  tempList.add("B");
  tempList.add("C");

  list.insert(0, tempList);
  tempList.clear();

  tempList.add("D");
  tempList.add("E");
  tempList.add("F");

  list.insert(1, tempList);

  print(list);  
}
```

> [Current Result]
>   [["D","E","F"],["D","E","F"]]

How i can get it right ?

Comment: You can use this code `list.insert(0, tempList.toList());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new list instead of clearing the original. Dart objects are passed by reference, so when you insert `tempList` into `list` and then call `tempList.clear()` you're erasing the list you've inserted into `list`, adding elements to it, and then adding a copy of it which results in the duplication you're seeing.

Example fix:

```dart
void main() {
  var list = <List<String>>[];
  var tempList = <String>[];

  tempList.add("A");
  tempList.add("B");
  tempList.add("C");

  list.insert(0, tempList);

  // Create a new empty list
  tempList = <String>[];

  tempList.add("D");
  tempList.add("E");
  tempList.add("F");

  list.insert(1, tempList);

  print(list);  
}
```

Comment: Dart objects passed by value. Dart object itself is a reference to heap that allocated for object. When you pass Dart object then you pass the copy (by value) of the reference to the heap. But this does not means that you pass the reference to object. You always pass new value that contains reference to heap.